# taylor approximation using mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, taylor-series

For a homework assignment:

Given the Taylor expansion for Exp[x/3]

write y[x]= Summation( n>=0 ) ( (a subscript n) * x^n ) .

Solve for the coefficients (a subscript n) up to order 10.

Comment: This sound much like homework. If it is so, please tag it accordingly.

Comment: This does not make sense. What is `y`? Are you just asking "How do I find the first 10 coefficients of the Taylor expansion of e^(x/3)?"

Comment: Sunday, you need to work to improve the quality of your questions. I am not the only one who is finding them inadequate.

Comment: well i try my best to ask questions related to my original set of questions...instead of just opting for copy paste

Comment: im new to mathematica n this kind of mathematical problems

Comment: Sunday, please try to ask your questions more clearly.  State the problem several different ways if you need to.  At least provide some context for the problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
CoefficientList[Series[Exp[x/3], {x, 0, 10}], x]

==> {1, 1/3, 1/18, 1/162, 1/1944, 1/29160, 1/524880, 1/11022480, \
1/264539520, 1/7142567040, 1/214277011200}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
(a[#]=SeriesCoefficient[Exp[x/3],{x,0,#}])&/@Range[0,10];??a
```

Answer (score 2):

googling for `mathematica power series`

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/PowerSeries.html

You will find Mathematica's help very thorough. You can access it from the Help menu, or by evaluating the following expression:

```
?Series
```

(or whatever you're interesting in the help for)

Comment: (I know very late to the party.) Truthfully, I don't find the help files that thorough, or at least they used to be more thorough in v.5 and below then they are in v.6 and above. Wolfram removed a lot of the "extraneous" examples that, while complex, often showed some details that are not shown currently. But, that's just my 2 cents. +1, for the documentation reference, though.